# Function call constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there anything like a "Call constraint" for C# ?

For instance i have the following function:

```
public UInt16 ConvertByteToUInt16 (byte[] buffer)
{
   if (buffer.Length != 2)
   {
       throw new InvalidArgumentException(); 
   }

   Convert();
}
```

Is it possible to write something like:

```
public UInt16 ConvertByteToUInt16 (byte[] buffer) : where (buffer.Lenght = 2)
{
    Convert();       
}
```

And if i call the function like that:

```
ConvertByteToUInt16 (new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF } )
```

I would like to get an error at compile time.
I am quite sure nothing like that exists on C# 2.0, but maybe on C# 4.0 ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just make it a method that accepts exactly 2 byte arguments?

Comment: You might want to look at Code Contracts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992

Comment: BoltClock: his example reflects a constraint of two or more, not just two.

Comment: You would not ever be able to receive a compile time error with this type of check anyway, as the program must run to know what the length of the `byte[] buffer` value is.  If you want to know more about why this isn't possible, read up on the halting problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: @Corey Ogburn: Huh? I'm pretty sure it's exactly 2.

Comment: @NathanAnderson has it right.  While it may seem trivial in the case of passing in a static array like in the example, if you were passing in an array stored in a variable, perhaps constructed from the contents of a file, there's no way the compiler could possibly know that that array variable contains 2 elements only.

Comment: And, in some cases, the array length would be undetermined until runtime (say, if the length & data were read in from a file)

Comment: @BoltClock, ah, you're right, I misread that the bottom example where he passes 3 bytes was supposed to be an example of an error. I misread, and yeah, I agree with your initial statement, just accept two bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in standard .NET. You need to manually check, then throw an appropriate exception:

```
public UInt16 ConvertByteToUInt16 (byte[] buffer)
{
    if (buffer.Length != 2)
        throw new ArgumentException("buffer needs to be of length 2", "buffer");
    Convert();       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as far as i know.

You can think about DBC (design by contract), (pre condition, post condition, invariants)

There is good example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/designbycontract.aspx

Comment: (a) You're making them pass in a new argument for something that is really a constant, which is proven by (b) you throwing an exception stating the value has to be 2 when (c) the user could really pass in 10 and not get the exception as long as the byte array length was also 10.

Comment: Good point, my example is useless (already fixed), he definitly should use constant.